# Javascript close on popup window not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, popup, modal-dialog

I am working on creating a modal popup window that works with an embedded video on a page. Everything is working great, EXCEPT for some reason I cannot get my close button to work. I've tried using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JO5u7J36fRI) tutorial along with a few others and I cannot for the life of me get this to work. What am I missing here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 7]> <html class="ie ie7 no-js" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]> <html class="ie ie8 no-js" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!--> <html lang="en-US" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=700, initial-scale=0.5" />

<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700|PT+Sans+Narrow:400,700|Roboto+Slab:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/respond.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

if (window.mobilecheck()) {
  window.location.replace("http://6minutestoskinny.com/index-cbm.html"+document.location.search);
} else {
setTimeout(function(){ 
    jQuery('#subscribeNow').show(); jQuery('#subscribeNow2').show();
    //jQuery('#optinNow').show(); jQuery('#optinNow2').show();
    //jQuery('#optinform').css('top', '700px');
}, 1638 * 1000);

setTimeout(function() { 
    /* make the form appear */
    jQuery('#optinform').fadeIn();
    //jwplayer().pause();

    jwplayer("player").setup({
          flashplayer: "player.swf",
          file: “video.mp4",
          width: "100%",
          height: document.getElementById("video-frame").offsetHeight-20,
          stretching: "exactfit",
          primary: "flash",
          controlbar: "false",
          volume: "100",
          autostart: "true",
          image: “image.jpg",
      });

//}, 1822 * 1000);
//}, 15 * 1000);
}, 500);
}

$('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
$('#mask').fadeIn(500);
return false;

$('button.close, #mask').live('click', function() {
$('#mask , #optinform').fadeOut(400, function() {
    $('#mask').remove();
});
return false;
});

$('button.close, #mask').live('click', function() {

$('#mask, .optinInfo').fadeOut(400, function() {

    $('#mask').remove();
});

return false;
});

});
</script>

<style type="text/css">

#mask {
    display: none;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#optinform {
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    width: 900px;
    /* height: 546px; */
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10%;
    left: 12%;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    filter:   progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#CC000000,endColorstr=#CC000000);
    }

#video-frame {
    height: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 720px;
    background: #222529;
    border: 11px solid #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px 9px #333;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px 9px #333;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px 9px #333;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 58.25%;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="optinform" class="optinInfo" style="display:none;">
<button type="button" class="close" style="float: right;margin: 5px;">Close</button>

    <div id="video-frame">
        <div id="player"><img src=“image.jpg border="0" alt="Loading the Player" style="width: 100%;" class="img-responsive" /></div>
    </div>

</div><!-- optin form -->
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `live()` is deprecated, you should switch to use jQuery `on()` instead and delegate the event from a static parent element, as the `<div id="mask">` is appended to the DOM and not in the DOM when the page is initially loaded. 
For example:

```
$(document).on("click", "button.close, #mask", function() {
   $('#mask , #optinform').fadeOut(400, function() {
     $('#mask').remove();
   });
 return false;
});
```

This is untested, but for reference: https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler, section "Direct and delegated events":

> "Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on()."

And http://api.jquery.com/live/:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live().

**Update:** As mentioned in the comments, suggested solution didn't fix the problem. I've just adjusted a Fiddle with the code provided in OP and noticed that the close button didn't work. Following adjustment should work:

```
$('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
$('#mask').fadeIn(500);
//return false;  <-- remove this line
```

Remove the `return false` below the `$("mask").fadeIn(500);`. Though I don't have the complete code (and no video playing), it's working in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vh68x1ge/embedded/result/) and should also work for your settings.

Comment: Thanks @matthias_h Changing to on() doesn't seem to do the trick either. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Crystal Did you only replace `live()` with `on()` or have you adjusted the function like suggested (starting from `$(document)`? Also noticed that you have the `live()` twice in your code, maybe because you tested something. If not already done, check if it works if you remove one of them and adjust the other like suggested. Additional question - do you get any errors (e.g. in the web dev console)?

Comment: Yes completely removed the second instance and added the code as instructed. I checked the console on load and there aren't any errors being thrown. Just not responding.

Comment: @Crystal Just updated my answer and think it should work with suggested adjustment.